# Error:(3, 31) java: package com.sun.tools.javac.jvm does not exist

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jvm

I'm trying to run my application on IntelliJ Idea and I get this error in terminal during Build :

**Information:java: Errors occurred while compiling module 'ProjectName'**

**Information:javac 11.0.2 was used to compile java sources**

**Information:12/07/2019 12:11 - Build completed with 2 errors and 0 warningsin 4 s 668 ms**

**Error:(3, 31) java: package com.sun.tools.javac.jvm does not exist**

This is my javaPath : **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin**

Line 3,31 :     *import com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.Gen;*

I need Some Help pLease

Comment: Is it Java 11 that you're using? Plus, can you provide the code snippet of the file whose (3, 31) line contains the error?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add a [mre]; what do you expect to be happening? The `com.sun.tools.javac.jvm` package exists in the `jdk.compiler` module but it isn't exported.